# How to write union query in doctrine?

Tags: mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I want to use union in doctrine, i searched a lot but didn't get any success, this is my union query in sql, how to convert this query in doctrine?

```
select * from (select orderid,tutorialId,points,allow_multiple,question,answer1,image1,correct1,answer2,image2,correct2,answer3,image3,correct3,answer4,image4,correct4,answer5,image5,correct5,'1' as istest,'' as content,'' as media,'' as media_type_id from tutorial_test

union

select orderid,tutorialId,'0' as istest,content,media,media_type_id,'' as points,'' as allow_multiple,'' as question,'' as answer1,'' as image1,'' as correct1,'' as answer2,'' as image2,'' as correct2,'' as answer3,'' as image3,'' as correct3,'' as answer4,'' as image4,'' as correct4,'' as answer5,'' as image5,'' as correct5  from tutorial_elements) a where a. tutorialId = 1 order by orderid asc
```

AND this one is my doctrine query

```
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT
                    tt.tutorialid
                FROM
                    TutorialTest tt
                UNION 
                SELECT te.tutorialid) tte
                WHERE tte.tutorialid = 1    

    ";
    $qb     = $this->Doctrine->createQuery($query);
    $tutorial_test  = $qb->getResult();
```

i researched alot but didn't get any success, if any one can help, million of thanks in advance fot that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well i have found a solution

We can use this query with RSM as following

"Usman is basically table name and class"

```
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('Usmans', 'u');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'orderid', 'orderid');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'tutorialId', 'tutorialid');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'points', 'points');

    $query = $this->Doctrine->createNativeQuery('SELECT * FROM usman', $rsm); 
    $tutorial_tests = $query->getResult();
```

AND we can use without ORM as

```
$testQuery = "
    select * from (
            select orderid, 
                tutorialId, 
                points, 
                allow_multiple, 
                question, 
                answer1, 
                image1, 
                correct1, 
                answer2, 
                image2, 
                correct2, 
                answer3, 
                image3, 
                correct3, 
                answer4, 
                image4, 
                correct4, 
                answer5, 
                image5, 
                correct5, 
                '1' as istest, 
                '' as content, 
                '' as media, 
                '' as media_type_id 
            from tutorial_test

            union

            select orderid, 
                tutorialId, 
                '0' as istest, 
                content, 
                media, 
                media_type_id, 
                '' as points, 
                '' as allow_multiple, 
                '' as question, 
                '' as answer1, 
                '' as image1,
                '' as correct1,
                '' as answer2,
                '' as image2,
                '' as correct2,
                '' as answer3,
                '' as image3,
                '' as correct3,
                '' as answer4,
                '' as image4,
                '' as correct4,
                '' as answer5,
                '' as image5,
                '' as correct5  
            from tutorial_elements
        ) a 
        where a. tutorialId = $tutorial_id 
        order by orderid asc
";

$resultSets = $this->Doctrine->getConnection()->fetchAll($testQuery);
```

Answer (score -3):

For Union Query has some Rules

(1) All SELECT Statements has same data type and same no of columns

In your select query has different datatype, no of columns are not match.

So you found Proble.

here is solution

```
select orderid, tutorialId, points, allow_multiple, question, answer1, image1, correct1, answer2, image2, correct2, answer3, image3, correct3, answer4, image4, correct4, answer5, image5, correct5,'1' as istest,'' as content,'' as media,'' as media_type_id 
from tutorial_test 

union

select orderid, tutorialId,'0' as istest, content, media, media_type_id,'' as points,'' as allow_multiple,'' as question,'' as answer1,'' as image1,'' as correct1,'' as answer2,'' as image2,'' as correct2,'' as answer3,'' as image3,'' as correct3,'' as answer4,'' as image4,'' as correct4,'' as answer5,'' as image5,'' as correct5, '1' as istest,'' as content,'' as media,'' as media_type_id  
from tutorial_elements 
where a. tutorialId = 1 
order by orderid asc
```

Comment: basically my sql query is perfectly fine, and it give me result in sql, my question is that how can i write this query in doctrine syntax.