# Doctrine2 - join on non related table

Tags: php, symfony, join, doctrine

I have some some tables which are not related and I try to join tables in my query:

```
$builder = $this->em()->createQueryBuilder();

$builder->select('main')
            ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'main')
            ->leftJoin('\Bundle\Path\To\Article', 'a', 'WITH', 'a.id = main.articleID');

$query = $builder->getQuery();

$query->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

$paginator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query);

return [
    'success' => true,
    'total'   => $paginator->count(),
    'data'    => $paginator->getIterator()->getArrayCopy()
];
```

and I get this message:

> Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction

Anybody could help me with this issue ?

Comment: What version of Doctrine DBAL/ORM are you using?

Comment: Why should the tables NOT be related to each other? Well you can use Native SQL to use an UNION select: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112971/how-to-write-union-query-in-doctrine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two options.

**Option 1**

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.date FROM table1 t1, table2 t2;
```

Obviously this would need modifying to meet your SQL statement/code structure, but I hope you get the point.

**Option 2**

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.date FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table2 t2;
```

Hope this helps :). However, in the future can I suggest googling first as this is a popular question.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but how to setup Option 1 as querybuilder?? is this even possible?